# node.js script doesn´t work

Tags: mysql, node.js

My script doesn't start. The error is:

```
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
```

How can I edit this to "outside strict mode"...?

I don't know how to edit this to work.

I have downloaded all modules.

Here's the source of script:

```
var SteamCommunity = require('steamcommunity');
var SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var log4js = require('log4js');
var SteamTradeOffers = require('steam-tradeoffers');
var async = require('async');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    database: 'sql_name',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin123',
    password: 'hidden'
});

var community = new SteamCommunity();
var offers = new SteamTradeOffers();
log4js.configure({
    appenders: [
        { type: 'console' },
        { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/bot_'+process.argv[2]+'.log' }
    ]
});
var logger = log4js.getLogger();

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/coderequest12/', function (req, res) {
    var assetids = req.query['assetids'];
    assetids = assetids.split(',');
    var partner = req.query['partner'];
    var token = req.query['token'];
    var checksum = req.query['checksum'];
    var steamid = req.query['steamid'];
    var senditems = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < assetids.length; i++) {
        if(assetids[i] == "") continue;
        senditems.push({
            appid: 730,
            contextid: 2, 
            assetid: assetids[i]
        });
    }
    var code = makecode();
    console.log(partner, token, checksum, assetids, senditems);
    offers.makeOffer({
        partnerAccountId: partner,
        accessToken: token,
        itemsFromThem: senditems,
        itemsFromMe: [],
        message: 'Security code: '+code
    }, function(err, r) {
        if(err) {
            logger.error('Error sending trade');
            logger.debug(err);
            res.json({
                success: false,
                error: err.toString()
            });
        } else {
            offers.loadPartnerInventory({
                partnerSteamId: steamid,
                tradeOfferId: r.tradeofferid,
                appId: 730,
                contextId: 2,
                language: 'russian'
            }, function(err, rr) {
                if(err) {
                    logger.debug(err);
                    res.json({
                        success: false,
                        error: err.toString()
                    });
                } else {
                    var names = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < senditems.length; i++) {
                        for(var a = 0; a < rr.length; a++) {
                            if((senditems[i].assetid == rr[a].id) && (!rr[a].ss)) {
                                names.push({market_hash_name: rr[a].market_hash_name, icon_url: rr[a].icon_url});
                                rr[a].ss = 1;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        code: code,
                        amount: checksum,
                        tid: r.tradeofferid,
                        items: names
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/coderequestrew/', function (req, res) {
    var names = req.query['names'];
    names = names.split(',');
    var partner = req.query['partner'];
    var token = req.query['token'];
    var checksum = req.query['checksum'];
    offers.loadMyInventory({
        appId: 730,
        contextId: 2
    }, function(err, items) {
        if(err) {
            logger.error('Error sending trade');
            logger.debug(err);
            res.json({
                success: false,
                error: err.toString()
            });         
        } else {
            var senditems = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                for(var a = 0; a < items.length; a++) {
                    if((names[i] == items[a].market_hash_name) && (!items[a].ss)) {
                        senditems.push({
                            appid: 730,
                            contextid: 2, 
                            assetid: items[a].id
                        });
                        if(senditems.length == names.length-1) break;
                        items[a].ss = 1;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(senditems.length == names.length-1) break;
                }
            };
            var code = makecode();
            console.log(partner, token, checksum, names, senditems);
            offers.makeOffer({
                partnerAccountId: partner,
                accessToken: token,
                itemsFromThem: [],
                itemsFromMe: senditems,
                message: 'Security code: '+code
            }, function(err, r) {
                if(err) {
                    logger.error('Error sending trade');
                    logger.debug(err);
                    res.json({
                        success: false,
                        error: err.toString()
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        code: code,
                        amount: -checksum,
                        tid: r.tradeofferid,
                        state: 2
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/checkTrade/', function (req, res) {
    var tid = req.query['tid'];
    offers.getOffer({
        tradeofferid: tid
    }, function(err, trade) {
        if(err) {
            logger.error('Error checking trade');
            logger.debug(err);
            res.json({
                success: false,
                error: err.toString()
            });
        } else {
            logger.debug(trade);
            if(trade.response.offer.trade_offer_state == 3) {
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    action: 'accept',
                    result: 'Coins have been added to your balance'
                });
            } else if(trade.response.offer.trade_offer_state == 7) {
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    result: 'You are declined trade',
                    action: 'cross'
                });
            } else {
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    error: 'You are not accept trade'
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

function cancelTrade(offerid) {
    offers.declineOffer({
        tradeOfferId: offerid
    }, function(err, log) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error('Could not cancel the trade #'+offerid);
            logger.debug(err);
            return;
        }
        logger.debug(log);
        logger.trace('Offer #'+offerid+' canceled');
    });
}

    query('SELECT * FROM `bots` WHERE `id` = '+pool.escape(process.argv[2]), function(err, res) {
    if((err) || (!res[0])) {
        logger.error('Cant find account');
        process.exit(0);
        return;
    }
    account = res[0];
    app.listen(3000+account.id);
    logger.trace('We got account info');
    account.twoFactorCode = SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(account.shared_secret);
    account.auth = false;
    logger.debug(account);
    community.login(account, login);
});

community.on('confKeyNeeded', function(tag, callback) {
    callback(null, time, SteamTotp.getConfirmationKey(account.identity_secret, time(), tag));
});

community.on('newConfirmation', function(confirmation) {
    var time = time();
    var key = SteamTotp.getConfirmationKey(account.identity_secret, time, 'allow');
    confirmation.respond(time, key, true, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            logger.error('Error on mobile auth');
            logger.debug(err);
            return;
        }
        logger.trace('Trade sucesfully confirmed');
    });
});

function query(sql, callback) {
    if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
        callback = function() {};
    }
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        logger.info('DB connection ID: '+connection.threadId);
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
            if(err) return callback(err);
            connection.release();
            return callback(null, rows);
        });
    });
}

function login(err, sessionID, cookies, steamguard) {
    if(err) {
        logger.error('Auth error');
        logger.debug(err);
        if(err.message == "SteamGuardMobile") {
            account.twoFactorCode = SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(account.shared_secret);
            logger.warn('Error in auth: '+account.twoFactorCode);
            setTimeout(function() {
                community.login(account, login);
            }, 5000);
            return;
        }
        process.exit(0);
    }
    logger.trace('Sucesfully auth');
    account.sessionID = sessionID;
    account.cookies = cookies;
    community.getWebApiKey('removed', webApiKey);
    community.startConfirmationChecker(10000, account.identity_secret);
}

function webApiKey(err, key) {
    if(err) {
        logger.error('Cant make apikey')
        logger.debug(err);
        process.exit(0);
        return;
    }
    account.key = key;
    logger.trace('API key bot '+account.accountName+' '+account.key);
    offersSetup();
    community.loggedIn(checkLoggedIn);
}

function offersSetup() {
    logger.trace('Loaded steam-tradeoffers');
    offers.setup({
        sessionID: account.sessionID,
        webCookie: account.cookies,
        APIKey: account.key
    });
}

function checkLoggedIn(err, loggedIn, familyView) {
    if((err) || (!loggedIn)) {
        logger.error('We arent logged in')
        process.exit(0);
    } else {
        logger.trace('Logged in');
        account.auth = true;
    }
}

function makecode() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

function time() {
    return parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000)
}
```

If you know more info please tell me in comments.

Comment: Doesn´t work. :( I add use strict - but no change

Answer (score 0):

add `'use strict';` on the very first line of the file.

Comment: doesn´t work CODE: node_modules/steam-totp/index.js:28
                        let code = exports.generateAuthCode(secret, offset);
                        ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: Are you using es6 ? and also which nodejs version you are using ?

Comment: I don´t know. What I must type to show version of nodejs?

Comment: in command prompt, type `node --version`

 Block-scoped declarations are supported outside of 'use strict' from nodejs v6.x.x , so if you are using older version then maybe updating the nodejs version may solve this error

Answer (score 0):

I fix the first error.

But now it´s showing:

```
            throw new Error(
        ^
Error: Problem with log4js configuration: ({ appenders:
   [ { type: 'console' },
     { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/bot_undefined.log' } ] }) - must have a property "appenders" of type object.
```